# How to find which values of a dataframe 'significantly' differ from a specific mean

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a Pandas DataFrame where one column is the temperature at half hourly intervals for the year.

> I want to create a column which on each row contains the mean value for that month at that time.

For example, in the row containing the value: "13:00:00 2018-02-02", I want the value to be the average of the temperature readings taken at 1pm during February. I am doing this so that I can identify which specific times have unusual reading of the temperature.

I have tried to do this by using .loc and for-loops.

Here is my code, I run this and get an error message.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dat

#df_train has been defined and is a Pandas DataFrame

df_train['Time']=df_train['Date and Time'].dt.time
df_train['Month']=df_train['Date and Time'].dt.month
times=np.array(df_train.loc[df_train['Date']==dat.date(2018, 1, 2)].Time)
means=[]
for i in range(1,13):
    df_hour=df_train.loc[df_train['Month']==int(i)]
    for time in times:

        df_hour=df_hour.loc[df_hour['Time']==time]
        means.append(df_hour['Temp'].values.mean())
```

I was hoping that I could then add means to my dataframe.

The error read:

```
C:\Users\ocallaghan_m\Desktop\Forecasting\Python_Code\Neural Networks\Non 
Recursive NN\48 steps type\Next Day With Day Type and BH & 
Weather\data.py:74: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  means.append(df_hour['Temp'].values.mean())
```

Any help with this code or any alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use pandas' `groupby()` method to achieve what you want (instead of the for loops).

Here is the code:

```
means = df_train.groupby(['Month', 'Time']).Temp.mean()
df_train.set_index(['Month', 'Time'], inplace=True)
df_train['Mean'] = means
df_train.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Or you could do: `df_train['Mean'] = df_train.groupby(['Month', 'Time']).Temp.transform('mean')`

Comment: @QuangHoang Yep that's better !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking advantage of [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) as such:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create DataFrame of random data
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=10, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) }) 
# Set the date to be the index
df.index = df['Date']
# Calculate the mean of each month and create new column
df['Monthly_Mean'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).transform('mean')
```

Result:

```py
    Date    Val     Monthly_Mean
Date            
2015-02-24  2015-02-24  1.764052    1.450280
2015-02-25  2015-02-25  0.400157    1.450280
2015-02-26  2015-02-26  0.978738    1.450280
2015-02-27  2015-02-27  2.240893    1.450280
2015-02-28  2015-02-28  1.867558    1.450280
2015-03-01  2015-03-01  -0.977278   0.025767
2015-03-02  2015-03-02  0.950088    0.025767
2015-03-03  2015-03-03  -0.151357   0.025767
2015-03-04  2015-03-04  -0.103219   0.025767
2015-03-05  2015-03-05  0.410599    0.025767
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to detect extremal values (low or high), I suggest that you use quantiles instead of the arithmetic mean because the estimators for this statistics are less sensitive to outliers than the estimator of the arithmetic mean, and you have no guarantee that arithmetic mean is going to be a good estimator of central tendency for temperature.

And even before doing this you should try to fit a linear trend to the month of february, in case temperatures are monotonously increasing/decreasing.

Maybe something like this would do  the job:

```
import numpy as np
from np.linalg import lstsq

temp_february = df.loc[df['Month'] == 2]


def remove_linear_temperature_trend(temp_feb):
    """Fit linear trend and subtract it from observations.

    """
    temp_feb['intercept'] = temp_feb.groupby('Time').temp.transform('mean')
    temp_feb['time_ix'] = temp_february['Time'].reset_index(drop=False).\
        groupby('Time').transform(
            lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True).index.to_frame())
    # works if rank of observations is not null, else you need regularized least squares
    temp_feb['trend'] = temp_feb.groupby('Time').apply(
        lambda x:lstsq(x['time_ix'], x['temp'] - x['intercept'])[0] * x['time_ix'] - x['intercept']
    )
    temp_feb['temp_detrended'] = temp_feb.apply(lambda x: x['temp'] - x['trend'], axis=1)
    return temp_feb


def spot_extremal_samples(temp_feb):
    """Spot ouliers (10 percents of the samples) based on detrended series.

    """
    temp_feb['percentile_5'] = temp_feb.groupby('Time').temp_detrended.transform(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 5))
    temp_feb['percentile_95'] = temp_feb.groupby('Time').temp_detrended.transform(lambda x: np.percentile(x, 95))
    outliers = temp_feb[(temp_feb['temp_detrended'] >= temp_feb['percentile_95']) |
                        (temp_feb['temp_detrended'] <= temp_feb['percentile_5'])]
    return outliers


extremal_samples_df = spot_extremal_samples(remove_linear_temperature_trend(temp_february))
```